# Grep Regex Match Anything Including Newlines

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, pattern-matching

I'm using the following command:

```
grep -o '<tag.*tag>\|^--.*'
```

However, I need to match newlines as well. How can I do this?

I have tried a few of the following options found: `(?s).*` `(.*?)` `.*?` `(.* )?`

I have to use `grep` because `awk` and other commands will take too long on loner lines in my data.

Anyone know how to fix my code to match newlines too? Your input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got it, needed to add the `-P` option and change the command to:

```
grep -oP '(<tag.*?tag>|^--.*)'
```

By using `-P`, I was able to get `grep` to match anything including newlines with the `.*?` pattern while also keeping my OR condition.